# simulink code generation for time series

Tags: simulink

I'm using MATLAB 2014B, I just tested the asbhl20 model for code generation.
When I built the model, it always said that:
'asbhl20/Variant/Previously saved data/From File' does not support timeseries input in this code generation mode. Consider converting the timeseries data into the array format. For information about the valid array format, see the documentation for the From File block.
I also save the time series data using '-v7.3', but it did not help.
Could anyone give me suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: The timeseries object is a MATLAB datatype hence it cannot be converted to C code and cannot be used for code generation.  What more of a suggestion do you need other than `Consider converting the timeseries data into the array format`?

Comment: How can I converting the timeseries data into the array format in simulink? Thanks

Comment: If your timeseries called `ts`, then then the equivalent array would be `dataAsArray = [ts.Time ts.Data]'`.  Note the transpose, since the `From File` block requires the first row to be the time points.  Open your block and press the `Help` button for more help.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it!